# open bootstrap modal from script in another page in php

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

in my application there is an inquiry form. My task is when i submit the inquiry form it send an email and if email is sent successfully I have to show a success message in a modal. I am writing my sendemail code inside `index.class.php` file. I have to show the modal in `services.php` file. How can I do that. I tried it by header location but it doesn't work. I didnt know whether it was right or not.
Here is my code:

index.class.php

```
 case "submitservceEnquiryMedical": 
          $mcpage = "services.php";
          if($this->sendMedicalservceenquiryEmail()) {
              $flmsg="success";
          }
          else {

             $flmsg="fail";
          }             
          header("Location: services.php?flMsg=$flmsg");
          exit();
          break;
```

Services.php

```
if(!EMPTY($_REQUEST['flmsg']))
        {
        $flmsg=$_GET['flmsg'];
        if($flmsg=='success') 
        {
        echo '<script> $("#Service-Enquiry").modal("show"); </script>';
        }
        else{
        echo '<script> $("#Service-Enquiry").modal("show"); </script>';
        }
        }
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-success">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Success</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You have succesfully submitted</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
```

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion here there are differents problems you can't use header location in that way and you are doing javascript injection inside php that really in this case no need.
My solution, or better what i do in my site it's this:
I do an ajax call to the PHP method(page, function, method it's the same), that sends the email, passing all the value from ajax and print an answer to the client/ajax in case the mail was sent or not...so OK or KO(in my case 00 is OK) and in the success of the ajax call i manage the answer 00 so ok etc....In your way you must do an ajax call to this

```
      sendMedicalservceenquiryEmail()
```

Return the flag and after in ajax at the success, if flag is success then modal show...I try to attach you my code if can be of help, just to look the architecture.

Code PHP where i do the ajax call, passing name, message, object of the email and destinatario is the recipient:

```
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');//Settiamo il timezone per l'orario
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
    $data = date("d-m-Y");
    $ora = date('G:i:A'); 
    /**
     * SESSION
     */
    $datiUtente = $_SESSION['datiUtente'];
    $utente = $datiUtente['username'];
    $profilo = $datiUtente['profilo']; 

    $email = $_REQUEST['destinatario'];
    $nome = $_REQUEST['nome'];
    $to = $email;
    $messaggio = trim($_REQUEST['messaggio']);
    $oggetto = trim($_REQUEST['oggetto']);
    $mittente = 'YOUR ACCOUNT@MAIL';

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        $msg = '88'.'|';
        $error='background: url("../img/error.png") no-repeat scroll left top #ffd0dc;
                border: 1px solid #ac343d;
                margin: 5px 0 15px;
                padding: 5px 5px 5px 40px;';
        $msg .= ("<div style='$error'>Formato Email non valido</div>"); 
        $msg = str_replace('\n', '', $msg);
        $msg = str_replace('\r', '', $msg);
        print $msg;
        exit;
    }

    $message = "Email in arrivo da server <b>$mittente</b><br/>
                Inviata da : <b>$nome </b><br/> 
                Profilo utenza : <b>$profilo </b><br/><br/><br/>
                $messaggio ";
    $subject = $oggetto;   

    $menof = "'-f" . trim($mittente) . "'";

        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='WIN')) {
          $eol="\r\n";
        } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='MAC')) {
          $eol="\r";
        } else {
          $eol="\n";
        } 
        $now = rand();
        $headers = 'From: YOUR NOME YOURSURNAME<YOUR ACCOUNT MAIL>'.$eol;
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: YOUR NOME YOURSURNAME<YOUR ACCOUNT MAIL>'.$eol;
        $headers .= 'Return-Path: YOUR NOME YOURSURNAME<YOUR ACCOUNT MAIL>'.$eol; //risposta a...
        $headers .= "Message-ID:<".$now." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">".$eol;
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$eol; //Per non andare nello spam
        $mime_boundary=md5(time());
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"".$eol; 

        if (mail(trim($to), trim($subject), wordwrap(trim($message)), trim($headers),trim($menof))){   
            $msg = '00'.'|';
            $msg .= ("L'email è stata inviata correttamente"); 
            $msg = str_replace('\n', '', $msg);
            $msg = str_replace('\r', '', $msg);
            print $msg;                 
            exit;           
        }
        else{
            $msg = '99'.'|';
            $msg .= ("Invio Email FALLITO!!!"); 
            $msg = str_replace('\n', '', $msg);
            $msg = str_replace('\r', '', $msg);
            print $msg;
            exit;   
        }
```

At the click of the button send mail i invoke this function that does the call at the php over

```
 function inviaEmailCliente(){

    var nome = $('#nomeMail').val(); 
    var messaggio = $('#messaggioMail').val(); 
    var oggetto = $('#oggettoMail').val(); 
    var destinatario = $('#destinatarioMail').val(); 

    if (oggetto == false){
        $('#contenutoInserimentoAna').html('Oggetto Obbligatorio');
        $('#modalAnagrafica').modal('show');
        $('#modalAnagrafica').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
           $('#modalVarAnagrafica').modal('hide');
        });
        return;
    }
    if (messaggio == false){
        $('#contenutoInserimentoAna').html('Messaggio Obbligatorio');
        $('#modalAnagrafica').modal('show');
        $('#modalAnagrafica').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
           $('#modalVarAnagrafica').modal('hide');
        }); 
        return;
    }
    if (nome == false){
        $('#contenutoInserimentoAna').html('Nome Obbligatorio');
        $('#modalAnagrafica').modal('show');
        $('#modalAnagrafica').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
           $('#modalVarAnagrafica').modal('hide');
        });
        return;
    }


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../index.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data : { azione : 'inviaEmailCliente',
               messaggio : messaggio,
               oggetto : oggetto,
               destinatario : destinatario,
               nome : nome },    
      success:function(data){

            dati = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

            if (dati.length > 0){
              dati = dati.split('|'); 

              if (dati[0] == '00'){
                $('#contenutoInserimentoAna').html(dati[1]);
                $('#modalAnagrafica').modal('show');
                $('#modalAnagrafica').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                   $('#modalAnagrafica').modal('hide');
                   $('#nomeMail').val(''); 
                   $('#messaggioMail').val(''); 
                   $('#oggettoMail').val(''); 
                   location.reload();
                });
              }
              if (dati[0] == '88'){
                $('#contenutoInserimentoAna').html(dati[1]);
                $('#modalAnagrafica').modal('show');
                $('#modalAnagrafica').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                   $('#modalVarAnagrafica').modal('hide');
                }); 
              }
              if (dati[0] == '99'){
                $('#contenutoInserimentoAna').html(dati[1]);
                $('#modalAnagrafica').modal('show');
                $('#modalAnagrafica').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                   $('#modalAnagrafica').modal('hide');
                }); 
              }

            }          
      },
      error:function (){
        alert ('Errore di comunicazione con il server');
      }                        
    }); 
 }
```

Html form of insert email, i don't paste the css...but hit is the form..

```
    <input type="hidden" id="destinatarioMail" value="WRITE HERE THE ADRESS WHERE SENDS THE EMAIL{email} TO@EXAMPLE.COM" >
        <div class="containerBorder padding3">
            <div class="alert-warning">
            <p><b>L'email sarà inviata a {email}</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon testoBlu" id="nomeInvioMail">Nome *</span>
                    <input type="text" id="nomeMail" class="form-control" aria-describedby="nomeInvioMail" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon testoBlu" id="oggettoInvioMail">Oggetto *</span>
                    <input type="text" id="oggettoMail" class="form-control" aria-describedby="oggettoInvioMail" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon testoBlu" id="messaggioEmailCli">Messaggio Mail *</span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="messaggioMail" aria-describedby="messaggioEmailCli" style="max-width: 724px; max-height: 130px;"> </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        <br>
        <div align="center">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Invia" id="inviaEmailCli" onclick="inviaEmailCliente()" />
        </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the html for the modal

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalAnagrafica" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabelAnagrafica">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                <h4 class="modal-title modalHeaderText" id="myModalLabelAnagrafica"><b>Anagrafica</b></h4>
              </div>
              <b><div class="modal-body" id="contenutoInserimentoAna">
              </div></b>
              <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                <div align="center">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I saw using ajax in another example. But actually this application have been developed by someone else in PHP PDO and my task is to do some updations. I am new to PHP PDO and I have to do this asap. Every function is written in a class file and we calls the function with objects.

Comment: I don't know how is your project but for example this: $("#Service-Enquiry").modal("show") it's not right because the id of the modal is modal-succes non service-inquiry i can't test your code but i suggest to change all doing an ajax call and manege it in a more tidy way.Bye

Comment: @aishwaryas also the html that you had insert is not ok in that way because you don't close php tags, it's impossible to work, you must have the html of the modal so or print the html form the php or close tag php write the html modal and reopen tag php at the end...but your php code is in error in that way...Ciao spizzi

Comment: Sorry, Here I copied only the relevant piece of code for my question.. all html and php tags are written properly in the page.

Comment: I have attached you also the html complete, with also the html of the modal....if can be of help copy and paste my code insert your email in the php invoke my php code so change the url of the ajax and delete the variable 'azione'(you don't need, i need to direct the call inside the my php) from the ajax call and try the architecture, my code is working well and email are not in spam...for sure you must modify it at your will and necessity...Ciao

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170953/discussion-between-aishwaryas-and-spizzi).

Comment: PDO and AJAX are not connected in any way, so try to use both